# Python: Iterating through dictionaries within dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this test dictionary:

```
addressBook = {'a' : {'Name' : 'b', 'Address' : 'c', 'PhoneNo' : '5'}, 'd' : {'Name' : 'e', 'Address' : 'f', 'PhoneNo' : '7'}}
```

I want to iterate through each dictionary within addressBook and display each value (name, address and phoneno).

I have tried this:

```
for x in addressBook:
    for y in x:
        print(y, "\t", end = " ")
```

However, this only prints the key of each dictionary (i.e. 'a' and 'b').

How do I display all the values?

Comment: Do you really need the addressBook to be a dictionary? Wouldn't a list of addresses do the job? Gives the key of addressBook any information to you?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you iterate through a dictionary by default python only iterates though the *keys* in the dictionary.

You need to use either the `itervalues` method to iterate through the values in a dictionary, or the `iteritems` method to iterate through the `(key, value)` pairs stored in that dictionary.

Try this instead:

```
for x in addressBook.itervalues():
    for key, value in x.iteritems():
        print((key, value), "\t", end = " ")
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using itervalues() over values()?

Comment: With Python 2.x, values returns an eager list of values and itervalues returns an iterator that gives you values on demand. In Python 3, the iter* functions have been removes and the items, values and keys functions return [dictionary views](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this

```
for k1,d in addressBook.items:
   for k2,v2 in d.items:
      print("{} :: {}".format(k2, v2))
```

However if all you want is to print the dictionary neatly, I'd recommend this

```
   import pprint
   s = pprint.pformat(addressBook)
   print(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dictionary only gives you the dictionary keys, not the values. If you want just the values, then use this:

```
for x in addressBook.values()
```

Alternatively, if you want both keys and values, use iteritems() like this:

```
for key,value in addressBook.iteritems():
        print key, value
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue with your code:

```
for x in addressBook:  # x is key from the addressBook dictionary.
    #- x is key and type of x is string. 
    for y in x:       # Now we iterate every character from the string.
        print(y, "\t", end = " ")  # y character is print
```

Try following:

```
for i in addressBook:
    print "Name:%s\tAddress:%s\tPhone:%s"%(addressBook[i]["Name"], addressBook[i]["Address"], addressBook[i]["PhoneNo"])


Name:b  Address:c   Phone:5
Name:e  Address:f   Phone:7
```